# SpanButton client property throws NullPointerException

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to get the client property on a SpanButton when clicked. It is throwing a NullPointerException.

I tested the same code with a regular button and it works just fine. I believe there could be a bug there.

Here is how you can recreate this issue from a barebone project:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    Button button = new Button("Button");
    button.putClientProperty("id", 100);

    SpanButton spanButton = new SpanButton("SpanButton");
    spanButton.putClientProperty("id", 200); 

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            int id = (int) evt.getComponent().getClientProperty("id");
            System.out.println("Standard Button action listener: id = " + id);
        }
    });

    spanButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            int id = (int) evt.getComponent().getClientProperty("id");
            System.out.println("Span button action listener: id = " + id);
        }
    });

    hi.addComponent(button);
    hi.addComponent(spanButton);
    hi.show();
```

If you click on the button, the output is printed correctly:

> Standard Button action listener: id = 100

If you click on the SpanButton, a NullPointerException is thrown. Upon investigation, I found out that the SpanButton getClientProperty("id") is returning null.

Note: I need to use the SpanButton because of its variable size support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getComponent()` use the aptly named `getActualComponent()`.

The [JavaDocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/) explain why:

> Identical to `ActionEvent#getComponent()` except for the fact that a lead component will be returned if such a lead component is available.
>
> This is important for components such as `MultiButton` which will return the underlying button instead.